# filemtime работает только после двойного нажатия submit

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Есть скрипт который загружает файл из формы. Через 10 секунд он должен перекинуть файл из папки upload в backup.

Проблема в том что скрипт работает только после двойного нажатия на submit. 
Функция filectime останавливает время только после двойного нажатия.

Форма загрузки файла

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" >
    Завантажити файл: <br><br>
    <input name="filename" type="file" ><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Завантажити" ><br><br>
</form>

<?php    
if(!file_exists("backup")){
    mkdir("backup");
}  

    $upload_dir = "upload";
    if (isset($_FILES['filename'])) {
        $filename = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
        $tmp_filename = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_filename, "$upload_dir/$filename");

        $upload_files = scandir($upload_dir);

        foreach($upload_files as $file){
            if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){

            $file_time = filemtime("$upload_dir/$file")."<br>";
            echo "filemtime = ".date('H:i:s',filemtime("$upload_dir/$file"))."<br>";
            echo "time = ".date('H:i:s',time())."<br>"; 

                if( time() - $file_time > 10){       
                        rename("$upload_dir/$file", "backup/$file");
                        echo "Файл $file переміщено в директорію backup";         
                }
            }           
        }  
    }  

    var_dump($_FILES);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверка на время выполняется единожды, а потом скрипт закрывается.
Для отсрочки времени нужно писать демона или можно воспользоваться `sleep(10)`

`set_time_limit(0);` `ignore_user_abort(true);` в помощь